# Android: Custom title bar doesn't fit on page

Tags: android, titlebar

Im giving my app a custom title bar and it seems to be half hidden behind the main page content: 
[image]

in **styles.xml** I have:

```
</style>
    <style name="NewsAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
</style>
```

**In main.xml** (The page with the title bar)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/tiny_4dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Top Row -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/tiny_4dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_head"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/text_head"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/headlines" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_head"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_head"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_head"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/img_head"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="@dimen/medium_15dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_head"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/tiny_4dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_custom1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/text_custom1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/headlines" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_custom1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_custom1"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_custom1"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/img_custom1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="@dimen/medium_15dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_custom1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        ..... and so on


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And **titlebar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grid" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_menu"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_title"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_8dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/small_8dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tiny_4dp"
        android:text="@string/title_title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title_minus"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/small_8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_minus" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title_add"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/small_8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Has something I've done caused it to cut off the title bar? Ive been following tutorials that say the bar should be 35dp high, although changing that doesnt seem to have much effect.

Comment: What if you use `android:layout_height="wap_content"` for the titleBar?

Comment: Use  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of  `android:layout_height="35dp"`

Comment: Thanks, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it :D

Comment: Already posted and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `height` of your `titlebar.xml` to make sure it gets the amount needed so other `Views` that this `layout` is included in doesn't take up room that it needs. So change the `height` to `wrap_content` instead of a fixed `dp`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   <!-- this guy here -->
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/small_8dp" >
```